# Mongoose and async

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have very problem in Async queries

I have to create an object runtime, i try with async 
my script:

```
async.forEach(myArray, function (item, callback){
    retrieveUser(username,item,function(err,item){
    console.log("Query");
         myobj.foo = item; //popolate the object
         callback(); // tell async that the iterator has completed
});
}, function(err) {
console.log('iterating done');
});
```

my result is

```
Query

Query

iterating done
Query

iterating done
Query

iterating done
Query

iterating done
Query

iterating done
Query

iterating done
Query
```

and my object is not populated correctly

Comment: Post your `retrieveUser` function also

Answer (score 0):

You used same variable name `item`. Update your function like below;

```
async.forEach(myArray, function (data, callback){
    retrieveUser(username,data,function(err,item){
        console.log("Query");
        myobj.foo = item; //popolate the object
        callback(); // tell async that the iterator has completed
    });
}, function(err) {
    console.log('iterating done');
});
```